# Grouping and Totaling Data in R Based on Two Groups

Tags: r, dataframe

Good Evening,

I have data that look like this

```
FY     Type     Total
2014   State    $5,000
2014   Federal  $2,596
2014   State    $5,123
2014   Federal  $2,567
2013   State    $5,555
2013   Federal  $2,784
2013   State    $5,562
2013   Federal  $2,556
```

How would I be able to get Totals by both FY and Type in R?

So that it can look like:

```
FY      Type    Total
2013    Federal $5,340
2013    State   $11,117
2014    Federal $5,163
2014    State   $10,123
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I'm not sure I understand what you're saying though. Convert to numbers? The total is in R as Numbers. Can you break the two steps down a little?

Comment: `$5,000` is not a number in R. It has a `$` and `,` in it, therefore, not a number.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Comment: Thank you for this! I had coded it to format it to a proper currency beforehand. How would the code change if it were a number to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert to numbers in order to get a sum, then it's a straightforward aggregation.  Here `transform` is used to temporarily convert the `Total` column to numeric, leaving the original data unchanged.

```
aggregate(
    Total ~ Type + FY, 
    transform(df, Total = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", Total))), 
    sum
)
#      Type   FY Total
# 1 Federal 2013  5340
# 2   State 2013 11117
# 3 Federal 2014  5163
# 4   State 2014 10123
```

Or a slightly different output with `xtabs`.

```
xtabs(Total ~ ., transform(df, Total=as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", Total))))
#       Type
# FY     Federal State
#   2013    5340 11117
#   2014    5163 10123
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I had coded it to format it to a proper currency beforehand. How would the code change if it were a number to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`.  After grouping by 'FY', 'Type', extract the numeric part of 'Total' with `parse_number`, get the `sum` and `paste` with `$` as prefix

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     group_by(FY, Type) %>% 
     summarise(Total = dollar_format()(sum(parse_number(Total))))
#    FY    Type   Total
#  <int>   <chr>   <chr>
#1  2013 Federal  $5,340
#2  2013   State $11,117
#3  2014 Federal  $5,163
#4  2014   State $10,123
```

NOTE: `dollar_format` is from `scales`, `parse_number` from `readr` and `summarise`, `group_by` from `dplyr`

---

We can also use `rowsum` from `base R`

```
rowsum(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]+", "", df1$Total)), interaction(df1[-3]))
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I had coded it to format it to a proper currency beforehand. How would the code change if it were a number to begin with?

Comment: @laura I think the `parse_number` will still extract the numeric part even if it is of other format with characters interspersed. Have you tested it?